# Set up Table to store variable number of fields per record?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

How should I set up my database / table, if I do not know the number of fields I would populate per record?

For example, if I have a web form that allows a user to enter all the cars he owns, and I don't want to limit him to a certain number, how would I store this in the database end?

The above problem extends to similar situations such as storing a user's order (variable number of items per order) etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS) instead you create child records in a dependent table that relate child entities (cars) with parent entities (users).  There is a concept known as database *normalization*, and the objective is that each table contains data for a single type of entity.

So you have a `user` table with the user information:

```
user_id | user_name | email             | ...
  1234  | User1     | user1@example.com | ...
  2356  | User2     | user2@example.com | ...
```

Then another table for storing the information of each car of a user:

```
user_car_id | user_id | car_label | make      | model | ...
          1 |   1234  | MyCar     | Ford      | 2011  | ...
          2 |   2356  | A Car     | Chevrolet | 2010  | ...
          3 |   1234  | MyOtherCar| BMW       | 2000  | ...
```

So instead of storing the info of the cars in the `user` table, you have a table for storing car (`user_car`) information related to each user by way of the `user_id` column.  This is an example of a one-to-many relationship, in which one user can have many related cars.

Comment: Thanks. That was very illustrative!

Comment: just note - in this model, you can not 'share' a car among multiple users (like if they sell it to one another)...

Answer (score 3):

this is an entire topic: database normalization.

the short answer is you make more than one table.

in your example  you would have person table, a car table, and a third that linked person to the car

Comment: Ok, so suppose I have a table specifically for cars where each car and its data resides along with a unique Car ID. And similar for person. What does the table that links the two look like. If a certain person adds multiple cars, would that equate to multiple records in this third table? Also, I'll look into DB normalization. Thanks

Comment: yes exactly. the middle table person_car for example would have at least two fields: person_id and car_id that would reference the other appropriate values. (you probably want dates here too for example)